# Avoid rendering transparent object

Tags: rendering

I am a newbie in Blender. The rendering speed of my animation is very slow (about 1-2min per frame) even with a pretty simple project. My project can be briefly described as scene A -> A disappear -> scene B appear -> B disappear -> scene C appears. Each scene only involves about 4-5 basic 3D shapes.

This is how I implement the project. When I only want to display scene A, I will make all the objects in other scenes to transparent, by setting the alpha value = 0. I wonder if this is the cause of the slow rendering, because all the objects will be rendered in every frame. Is there any way to optimize the situation?

Comment: Hi :). Why not disable the objects from rendering instead? Transparent objects still need to be loaded into memory and may slow things down.

Comment: @JachymMichal, oh you are right. I think I can separately render the 3 scenes and then use video editing software to combine them. thanks!